# How can I integrate with lock screen player controls from Adobe Air?

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, audio, air

I'm starting to write an app in Adobe Flex for iOS and Android. The only piece of the puzzle I haven't figured out so far is how I can integrate with the OS media player controls in iOS and Android.

Comment: I doubt you can with AIR alone.  You may be able to use a Native Extension to do so; assuming the underlying OS exposes those controls somehow.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Is there a good resource out there on how to make a Native Extension? I may be interested in creating and open-sourcing such an extension.

Comment: I assume Google will help you find resources.  I've heard the documentation was not complete before the last Adobe restructuring, so it's a bit of guess work for platforms other than iOS.  I haven't started this myself, though.  Start here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html .  And Nick ( http://quetwo.com/  ) has posted a bunch of stuff on creating Windows / Mac Native Extensions.  I Assume the same concepts apply to Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @www.Flextras.com mentions the only way to do this is to create a Native Extension [How to extend air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html)

There are lots of examples out there and some open source libs for various features, but nothing I can see that offers support for lock screen audio. Creating your own may be the best solution, good luck.